# R ggplot: how to make a legend with labels combining correspondent frame elements in two columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to plot a set of points showing the labels on the plot. Since the labels include long names, I was thinking to enumerate the labels and to report the corresponding names in the legend, like:

1. Region A
2. Region B
   ....
   ....

My frame includes 4 columns:
X, Y, Names, Numbers

And my code, so far, is like:

```
ggplot(data.f,aes(X,Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Numbers),hjust=-0.4, vjust=0, size=6) +
  ylab("Y") +
  xlab("X")
```

producing the attached plot:

[image: geom_point labels]

Do you know how to automatically show the correspondent names in the legend using the column "Names"?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want but it may be an alternative option that would give some intuition.

Grouping, coloring or faceting by *Names* aren't helpful because of the smoothing line. It is possible to tweak margins using `theme(plot.margin = unit(c(., ., ., .)))` to open space for a manual legend and paste the region names there along with numbers using `paste0(data.f$Numbers, ". ", data.f$Name)`. However, you will need a large space for ~60 region names and this will affect the readability of the graph.

My alternative suggestion would be to display region names on hover over to keep things clean. Here is a `ggiraph` implemetation:

```
# importing packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggiraph)

# creating a similar data frame
set.seed(147)
data.f <- data_frame(
  X = rnorm(10),
  Y = rnorm(10),
  Name = paste("Region", LETTERS[1:10]),
  Numbers = 1:10
)

# building the ggplot with interactive features
g <- ggplot(data = data.f, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = Numbers), 
    hjust = -0.4, 
    vjust = 0, 
    size = 6
  ) +
  geom_point_interactive(aes(tooltip = Name, data_id = Numbers)) +
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y")

# building the ggiraph output
ggiraph(ggobj = g)
```

If you want to learn more about `ggiraph` and further customize your graph, you can find additional details in the documentation: [Using ggiraph](https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/articles/offcran/using_ggiraph.html)

Comment: Thank you! That's useful for interactive inspection! However, I need a figure to show the regions on a printed version. Ho do you use paste to add Numbers and Names on the legend? Thank you!